# Motivation for Artin algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> An Artin algebra is an algebra $\Lambda$ over a commutative Artin ring R that is a finitely generated R-module.

My questions are:

1. Why is Artin algebra defined this way?
2. Why do we generalize finite dimensional algebra to Artin algebra?

Thank you :)

Comment: I think that [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382742/why-auslander-and-reiten-were-so-interested-in-artin-algebras) answers some of your questions. It is the representation theory which matters. You should focus your question more, so far it is too general I think.

Comment: The last sentence of the answer at the duplicate also applies here: "I tried to provide a succinct answer to your question, but you can find a far better answer by yourself: As you proceed in your studies keep a sharp eye on the particular properties of Artin algebras you use and try to imagine how hard ``life'' would be without them!"